# how to combine two tables and count their values as one?

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to get the total numbers of committed crimes when combining the two tables. 
But I want to count the numbers for each crime being committed and also display the values of those that has not being committed as 0, How can i achieve this using mysql?
my code:

```
  SELECT count(offense_id) 
    AS totalnumber,(
    select offense_description
    from offense
    where offense.offense_id = case_crime.offense_id
    )as crimeName
    from case_crime
    group by offense_id
```

[image: case_crime table]

[image: offense table]

[image: output but i also want to display offense_description that no crime being committed]

Comment: I also want to display the numbers of other crimes not being committed and display 0 for those values.Any help would be appreciated.Thanks.

Comment: Please! Do not post images. Give us some data to work with. Also, please explain about those tables and their relationships.

Comment: the first image is the case_crime table the second one is the offense table, i want to combine the case_crime table and the offense table and count the values for each offense_description. I also want to display the values of offense_description as 0.

Comment: the third image is my output but it doesnt display the other offense_description.

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for a LEFT OUTER JOIN

Something like

```
SELECT offense.offense_id
    , offense_description
    , count(case_crime.case_id) as Total_Number

from offense
LEFT OUTER JOIN case_crime ON offense.offense_id = case_crime.offense_id
group by offense.offense_id
```

I'll admit, I'm a TSQL guy, so I would handle the COUNT(*) returning null when there are no cases with the specified offense using: `ISNULL(COUNT(case_crime),0)`

Other SQL variants might use `COALESCE( COUNT(case_crime), 0)`

Comment: Thanks Stan bu I got an error with the isnull :#1582 - Incorrect parameter count in the call to native function 'ISNULL'

Comment: That's my TSQL roots.  COUNT(*) for a left join will return NULL when there is nothing on the LEFT.....so you need to convert the NULL to zero using the appropriate function.  I adjusted the answer

Comment: yeah its working but the output display all 1. What I want is that the offense_description in the case_crime table will be have an output of 1 and I want to combine the offense_description not being listed of the case_crime and display the value as 0. since no crime has being commited for that.

Comment: can anyone please help me with this?

Comment: The count is wrong, it should be count(b.crime_caseid) - like in my answer :) - counting any column will always give you 1 for each record.

Comment: Another difference between TSQL and mySQL, and proof that I should not answer questions during boring meetings.

Answer (score 0):

To get a list of all your offenses and the count of registered crimes, you need to use the LEFT JOIN between the two tables .... something like this SQL:

```
SELECT a.offense_id, a.offense_description, count(b.crime_caseid) as total
FROM offense a LEFT JOIN case_crime b
ON a.offense_id = b.offense_id
group by a.offense_id;
```

[Here is a SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/88048/1)   to play around with :)

Comment: thanks its working on fiddle but on my phpadmin its not working i got the error: Unknown column 'b.crime_caseid' in 'field list' .Thanks again.

Comment: Sorry about that - I entered the wrong table name in my fiddle. I edited the answer to correct this. Another time you should maybe dump the SQL to create the tables or do it for us in a Fiddle? :)